# lemon library file bipartite_matching.h missing

Tags: c

I install the library in linux system as described on the following website https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/wiki/InstallLinux.

I want to find the maximum matching of a lemon bipartite graph, and found that there is a algorithm in lemon library http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/latest-svn/a00381.html.

When I `#include <lemon/bipartite_matching.h>`, the compiler reports that no file named `bipartite_matching.h` exists in lemon, so I checked the file in compressed file download from https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/wiki/Downloads, and I can't find `bipartite_matching.h`.
Does anyone know possible reasons for that missing file?

Comment: How did you install the library? What type of system are you using? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: I have updated my text

Comment: Did you execute `make install`? Did any of the build steps failed? Do you have `/usr/include/lemon`? Maybe it installed inside `/usr/local/include/lemon`? Che kc the logs from `make  install` and see where it installed.

Comment: Yes, I execute `make install` and no any step failed.
I have `/usr/include/lemon` but no file name `bipartite_matching.h` in it.

Comment: I also check the `.tar.gz` file download from website,and also don't see the file name `bipartite_matching.h`

Comment: If you followed the instructions on the website, the library will be installed in `/usr/local`. Please check if the file is in `/usr/local/include`. If you used something like `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<directory>`, please state this in your question.

Comment: Which Linux distribution do you use? Maybe there is already a pre-packaged library available. for example https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=liblemon-dev

Comment: Then probably the documentation is outdated or something. The file is in something called [lemon-0.x](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/browser/lemon-0.x/lemon/bipartite_matching.h), but there is also [lemon-1.2](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/browser/lemon-1.2). Which version did you installed?

Comment: I install 1.3.1 version,with your reminder,I check the`.tar.gz` file of other version and find that there are only`lemon-0.x `version has the` bipartite_matching.h` file. The file just disappeared after the version 0.7

Comment: I try to install the 0.7 version,but it failed when I use make file......

Comment: I expect the code has just been renamed in lemon-1.x. Can you find the same functionality in lemon/bpgraph.h and lemon/matching.h?

Comment: Your link refers to an outdated version of the library (0.7.90_svn3524
). New versions of the library don't include the `bipartite_matching.h` file.